# Veronese embedding as ring isomorphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

At the level of rings, the Veronese map corresponds to isomorphisms like
$$k[w,x,y,z]/(wz - xy, wy-x^2, xz - y^2) \cong k[a^3, a^2 b, a b^2, b^3].$$
This isomorphism is the statement that the relations satisfied by the monomials of degree 3 generate exactly the same ideal as $I = (wz - xy, wy-x^2, xz - y^2)$. One direction is obvious (corresponding to a well-defined map $\to$): the monomials of degree 3 certainly satisfy these three relations.

The other direction seems hard. It encodes the idea that we have found *all* the relations, which is certainly an extremely hard general problem. How would one prove such a thing explicitly?

I believe all of this can be formulated in much higher geometric language as an isomorphism of $\operatorname{Proj}$ constructions, but that language should surely encode a concrete argument.

Comment: I think [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/227255/) may answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect there are fancier more systematic ways to prove it, but here's a simple hands-on proof.   By the easy direction we have a surjective homomorphism $f:R\to S$ where $R=k[w,x,y,z]$ and $S=k[a^3, a^2 b, a b^2, b^3]$, and the kernel of $f$ contains $I$.  To show that the kernel of $f$ is contained in $I$, it suffices to show the following.

> **Claim**: If monomials $m=w^i x^j y^k z^\ell$ and $m'=w^{i'}x^{j'}y^{k'}z^{\ell'}$ are such that $f(m)=f(m')$, then $m\equiv m'\pmod I$.

Why does this suffice?  Well, since $f$ maps monomials to monomials, if $p\in \ker f$, then the monomials in $p$ must map to identical monomials in $S$ whose coefficients cancel out (since monomials in $S$ are linearly independent, that's the only way $f(p)$ can be $0$).  But then the Claim would show that the monomials of $p$ also cancel out mod $I$, so $p\in I$.

So, let's prove the Claim. We have $f(m)=a^{3i+2j+k}b^{j+2k+3\ell}$ and similarly for $m'$, so we must have $$3i+2j+k=3i'+2j'+k'$$ and $$j+2k+3\ell=j'+2k'+3\ell'.$$

We will use induction on $i+i'+\ell+\ell'$.  Let us first suppose that $i+i'+\ell+\ell'=0$.  Then our equations are just $2j+k=2j'+k'$ and $j+2k=j'+2k'$.  This easily implies $j=j'$ and $k=k'$, and so $m=m'$ and we are done.

Now suppose $i+i'+\ell+\ell'>0$; we may assume without loss of generality that $i>0$.  If $i'>0$, we can cancel $w$ from both $m$ and $m'$ to reduce to a case where $i+i'+\ell+\ell'$ is smaller.  If $\ell>0$, we can use the relation $wz\equiv xy\pmod{I}$ on $m$ to decrease $i$ and $\ell$ by $1$ and increase $j$ and $k$ by $1$, reducing to a case where $i+i'+\ell+\ell'$ is smaller.  Similarly if $k>0$ we can use the relation $wy\equiv x^2\pmod{I}$ on $m$ to reduce to a case where $i+i'+\ell+\ell'$ is smaller.

So, we may assume that $i'=\ell=k=0$.  Our two equations then reduce to $$3i+2j=2j'+k'$$ and $$j=j'+2k'+3\ell'.$$  But now observe that the second equation implies $2j\geq 2j'+k'$ which makes the first equation impossible since $i>0$.  Thus this case is impossible, completing the proof.

Comment: Small typo: you seem to have written "kernel of $f$ contains $I$" when you meant "kernel of $f$ is contained in $I$" the second time. Otherwise thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for.