# What is a cubic ideal/partial cubic ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Can anyone explain to me as simple as possible what a cubic ideal/partial cubic ideal is? I know what an ideal is in Ringtheory but I couldn't find anything about a cubic ideal or about partial cubic ideals.

Any help appreciated

Comment: Could you share where you encountered this idea? Context would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The term "partial cubic ideal" does not seem to exist. What I found about cubic ideals, are 1.) [Ideal of the twisted cubic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160924/ideal-of-the-twisted-cubic) 2.) Cubic ideals in polynomial rings $K[x_1,\ldots ,x_n]$ given by homogeneous polynomials of degree $3$.